# Spring, HandleAfterCreate, Reactor, EventBus IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, project-reactor

I want to spawn a separate thread(using `Reactor` or `EventBus`) after capturing `@HandleAfterCreate` Event in `SpringBootApplication`. I am facing `IllegalStateException` , what exactly is going on? I searched a lot and found that a dispatcher does not allow either copy or storing of the dispatched object. What does it mean? Please help.

```
@Autowired
Reactor reactor
@HandleAfterCreate
void someFunction(Customer newCustomer) {
    reactor.notify("customer-events", Event.wrap(customer)); //Exception Here
}
```

**Exception Message**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Dispatcher has been shutdown
    at reactor.event.dispatch.BaseDispatcher.dispatch(BaseDispatcher.java:42)
    at reactor.event.dispatch.BaseLifecycleDispatcher.dispatch(BaseLifecycleDispatcher.java:28)
    at reactor.core.Reactor.notify(Reactor.java:211)
    at reactor.core.Reactor.notify(Reactor.java:223)
    at com.gs.rainbow.cep.reactors.Publisher.publishCustomers(Publisher.java:27)
    at com.gs.rainbow.cep.events.CustomerEventHandler.handleAfterCreate(CustomerEventHandler.java:51)
```

**My Environment**

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.2.6
- com.h2database:h2:1.4.189
- org.projectreactor:reactor-spring:1.0.0